# How to display the data in a project in android studio from mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

How can I fetch the data from Mysql and display it in android? can you give me examples or sources?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Android support Sqlite database, if you wan't to use server side mysql then you need to create PHP api which will return json of mySql database content and you can use in your android app